# Dockerfile: how to update and pass build args between RUN commands or stages?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I am trying to write a Dockerfile that has two build args:

- REPO
- TAG

The repo is a GitHub URL and the TAG is a release version.
I would like to have only the REPO as required, while the TAG should be optional. However, I want to update its value with the latest release tag available and use it in other RUN commands or even better other build stages.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  cve_search:
    image: cve_search
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/cve-search/Dockerfile
      args:
        - REPO=${REPO:-https://github.com/cve-search/cve-search.git}
        - TAG=${TAG:-v4.0}
    environment:
      - REPO=${REPO:-https://github.com/cve-search/cve-search.git}
      - TAG=${TAG:-v4.0}
```

and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine AS builder

# The repository url
ARG REPO
# The release tag
ARG TAG

# Print input args
# Repo 1: https://github.com/cve-search/cve-search.git
RUN echo Repo 1: $REPO
# Tag 1: v4.0
RUN echo Tag 1: $TAG

# Simulate new Tag version available from script
RUN TAG=v4.1.0 &&\
    export TAG

# Test new tag
# Tag 2: v4.0
# How to fix it and print
# Tag 2: v4.1.0
# ?
RUN echo Tag 2: $TAG
```

The command to build the image is:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

How do I make the last echo command to print the updated version of the TAG variable?

Answer (score 0):

Each RUN command runs in it's own shell, so when you export an environment variable, it disappears when the RUN command in done.

ENV commands set environment variables that persist through the whole file, so if you do

```
ENV TAG=v4.1.0
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: Ok, the ENV command works, however I need to get the TAG value from a script. Is it possible to use a script output as the ENV TAG value ?

Comment: I don't think you can use dynamic values in ENV statements. What you can do, maybe, is get the value and use it in a single RUN statement. If you look at something like the Nginx Dockerfile, you can see that they have a single gigantic RUN statement where they do stuff with environment variables https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/ef8e9912a2de9b51ce9d1f79a5c047eb48b05fc1/mainline/debian/Dockerfile